# WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Estoy tratando de ejecutar un programa que usa la librería selenium y me tira el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\prueba_nuevo_bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    bot=FacebookBot()
  File "C:\Python34\FacebookWebBot.py", line 115, in __init__
    webdriver.PhantomJS.__init__(self, desired_capabilities=dcap)
  File "C:\Python34\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python34\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 84, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Tengo el archivo phantomjs.exe en la carpeta C:\DriverPath\Bin\ pero cuando imprimo self.path para ver donde está buscando ese archivo el path que me imprime es [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] con ese punto en lugar de la barra y la "B" . Como se puede arreglar este error, que significa ese path defectuoso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví así, en la librería C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.4.2-py3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py modificar la línea después del try a lo que está ahora.

```
 def start(self):

>         """
>         Starts the Service.
> 
>         :Exceptions:
>          - WebDriverException : Raised either when it can't start the service
>            or when it can't connect to the service
>         """
>         try:
> 
>             self.path = "C:\\DriverPath\\Bin\\phantomjs"
```